# HTTP-запрос DELETE из AngularJS в Django REST - как передать JSON параметр?

Tags: json, django, angularjs, http, django-rest-framework

Удаление по `pk`, запрос вида `DELETE /myapi/pk/`, где `pk` - это число:

```
def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        print(pk);
        item = self.model.objects.get(item_id=pk)
        item.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

В AngularJS:

```
$http.delete('/myapp/' + pk + '/');
```

где `pk` - также число.
Все работает. `print(pk)` - выводит искомое число.

Мне же нужно удалять не только по `pk`, а и при необходимости - по другому полю, который имеет текстовый формат.

Чтобы удалить только по текстовому полю, назовем его `item_name`, я пытаюсь использовать следующую функцию:

```
def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        print(request.GET['item_name']);
        item = self.model.objects.get(item_name=request.GET['item_name'])
        item.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

В AngularJS:

```
$http.delete('/myapp/' + pk + '/', {'item_name': item.name});
```

где `pk` - также число, item.name - текст.
Пояснение: `pk` все равно использую, т.к. `DELETE`-запрос требует формата `/url/pk/`

`print(request.GET['item_name'])` - ничего не выводит, `ошибка 500`. Т.е. `item_name` не передается в запросе.

Чтобы проверить, делаю то же самое с `pk`:

```
def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        print(request.GET['id']);
        item = self.model.objects.get(item_name=request.GET['id'])
        item.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

В AngularJS:

```
$http.delete('/myapp/' + pk + '/', {'id': pk});
```

где `pk` - то же число.
Снова `print(request.GET['id'])` ничего не выводит, ошибка 500.

Если я правильно понимаю, в запросе `DELETE` отбрасываются JSON-данные, т.е. `request.data`? Как тогда передать параметр?

Comment: пиши просто  get или пост зачем заморачиваться $http.get $http.post

Comment: @korolariya как тогда REST узнает, что нужно удалить объект? 
    В `urls.py`  у меня такие строки: 
    `url(r'^myapp/(?P<pk>\d+)/', MyAPI.as_view()),
    url(r'^myapp$', MyAPI.as_view())`

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь передавать данные в теле запроса DELETE.Это противоречит спецификации.

У вас два варианта. Использовать DELETE и передавать идентификатор в параметре запроса, либо использовать POST запрос с указанием действия.(по хорошему противоречит REST)

Для ознакомления прочитайте [статью с хабра](http://habrahabr.ru/post/50147/).

[Спецификация HTTP/1.1, part 2: Message Semantics](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-19#section-6.7)

> Bodies on **DELETE** requests have **no defined semantics**.  Note that
> sending a body on a DELETE request might cause some existing
> implementations to **reject the request**.

---

[RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7)

> The **DELETE** method requests that the origin server delete the resource
> **identified** by the **Request-URI**.

p.s. Формулируйте суть вопроса, а не вываливайте всю портянку с кодом. Суть вашего вопроса - почему не передаются данные при использовании DELETE метода :) Если бы спросили именно так - ответ получили бы в разы быстрее.